# Problem of Using 'sed' to Edit Code

Tags: linux, sed

```
for(int i=0; i<oldmethod(a, 7); i++) {
  sum += oldmethod(b*b+i-3, i%a);
```

---->

```
 for(int i=0; i<newmethod(7, 0, a); i++) {
  sum += newmethod(i%a, 0, b*b+i-3);
```

I had

```
sed 's/old(\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]*\),\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]*\))/new(\2, 0, \1)/'
```

But it only changes the first oldmethod, like

```
 for(int i=0; i<newmethod(7, 0, a); i++) {
   sum += oldmethod(b*b+i-3, i%a);
```

Comment: This looks like it would be safer to use an IDE to refactor this code. Using regular expressions for code is dodgy.

Comment: Why don't you just make `oldmethod()` call `newmethod()`?

Answer (score 1):

One of the arguments in your second line is `i%a`.  That won't be matched by your regex because you haven't included `%` in your character class `[-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+]`.  Try

```
sed 's/oldmethod(\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+%]*\),\([-a-zA-Z 0-9./*+%]*\))/newmethod(\2, 0, \1)/'
```

You may find further instances using other characters you've not considered, such as `_` in variable names, or `(` and `)` in nested calls to other functions.  You'll have to keep extending the subexpression as you encounter such uses.

Comment: Perhaps simplify: `[^,]*` instead of `[lots of characters]*`

Answer (score 0):

A more generic possibility:

```
sed -E 's/old([^,]*\()([^,])*, ([^)]*)\);/new\1\3, 0, \2);/' file
```

Output:

```
for(int i=0; i<newmethod(7, 0, a); i++) {
  sum += newmethod(i%a, 0, b*b+i-3);
```

Comment: You'll want to use less greedy elements: `[^,]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: @glennjackman edite the question, thanks. IS ok now?

Comment: Now that I look at it again, the 3rd group should be non-close-parenthesis